# Gluing semi-edges of a square starting from corners

Tags: general-topology

Half side lengths of a unit square are glued together so that, just like corners, side centers are also becoming a point. Is it now homeomorphic  to a sphere with a hole or to a no-holed un-punctured  sphere?

[image: GluedSquare]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is homeomorphic to a sphere no holes assuming the gluing directions are "$aa^{-1}$" for each of the edges.  You can take a piece of paper and identify the edges in the given manner.  You'll see that you haven't introduced an extra hole.

Otherwise, you can compute the Euler characteristic.  There are 5 vertices, 4 edges, and 1 face so $\chi = 5 - 4 + 1 = 2$, and classification of surfaces tells you this is a sphere.

If you glue according to $"aa"$, then there is only 1 vertex, and the edges and faces remain the same so $\chi = 1 - 4 + 1 = -2$ so you need to check whether or not it is orientable and classification of surfaces will give you your result.